# How to show multiple rows of SQL queries in MySQL Workbench UI?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Now, this question isn't about MySQL queries, result rows or anything related to the databases itself, but the program MySQL Workbench.

I have tens of tables open (both altering the table and editing rows/columns) in the program and can only see around 10 tabs in the UI at once as there is only one row of them. Using the left and right arrows to show more tabs is very slow and annoying.

So, is there any way to show multiple rows of tabs or somehow otherwise increase the space for them? Preferences have nothing related to it except the font and searching the web only returns meaningless stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No. However, you might want to file a [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/) that requests adding "Scripting Editor Tabs" under Preferences --> Appearance --> Fonts.

Also, it's worth noting that the [Control] + [Tab] key shortcut selects the next tab, and [Control] + [Shift] + [Tab] selects the previous tab.